# Necessary and/or sufficient condition for invertibility of the gradient of a polynomial of $m$ variables, viewed as a self map of $\mathbb{R}^m?$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, polynomials, projective-geometry

I was wondering whether the following is true, and if not, is something known in this direction?

Let $P:\mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}$ be a degree $r$ polynomial (not necessarily homogeneous) that contains only even powers of the components $x_i, 1\le i \le m$ and their products. Then $\nabla P:\mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}^m$ is invertible if and only if the polynomial $P$ satisfies **Condition C:** contains **all** the components $x_i$ with some unmixed powers $\lambda_ix_i^{r_i}, \lambda_i > 0 \forall 1 \le i \le m$ for some *even* $r_i \in \mathbb{N}.$

**The motivation behind my question is:**

**(Necessity)** assuming the special form $P(x):=\sum_{i=1}^{m}\lambda_ix_i^{r_i}, \lambda_i>0, r_i$ even, the answer is yes, i.e. in order for $\nabla P:\mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}^m$ to be invertible, it has to contain every $\lambda_ix_i^{r_i}, \lambda_i>0,$ for otherwise $\nabla{P}$ won't even be injective, because $\frac{\partial{P}}{\partial{x_k}}\equiv 0,$ if $x_k$ is not present in $P.$

**(Sufficiency)** If $P(x)=\sum_{i=1}^{m}\lambda_ix_i^{r_i}, r_i$ even, then clearly $\nabla{P}$ is invertible, and is given by $\nabla{P}(x_1 \dots x_m):=(({\frac{x_1}{\lambda_1}})^{\frac{1}{r_1-1}}, ({\frac{x_2}{\lambda_2}})^{\frac{1}{r_2-1}}, \dots {{(\frac{x_m}{\lambda_m}})}^{\frac{1}{r_m-1}}).$ Here note that $({\frac{x_i}{\lambda_i}})^{\frac{1}{r_i-1}}, 1 \le i \le d$ is uniquely defined in reals precisely because $r_i$ is even.

So I was wondering whether the same **condition C** (for $P$) is also a necessary and/or sufficient condition when $P(x)$ contains *mixed power*s like $x_1^2x_2^4$ etc. If the general answer is no, is there a class of polynomials where the above is true? I'd be happy to see some answers *even for homogeneous polynomials*.

**My question is also motivated by these two questions I asked earlier:**

[Is there any sufficient or equivalent condition for the invertibility of a regular map, i.e. a self map of $\mathbb{R}^m$ with polynomial components?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/460175/is-there-any-sufficient-or-equivalent-condition-for-the-invertibility-of-a-regul) (it got no answer)

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4845664/how-to-prove-that-this-polynomial-function-of-m-variables-is-strictly-convex (it got a negative answer)

**Update:** Initially I forgot to mention that $P$ must have all coefficients non-negative, but upon the initial answer given by Iosif Pinelis, I'm adding that bit.

Comment: "it satisfies Condition C" ... What do you mean by "it" here: $P$ (hopefully) or $\nabla P$ (as it is now written)?

Comment: @IosifPinelis Thanks for bringing this to my attention, I meant $P,$ I just edited the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Condition C is not sufficient.

A counterexample is given by $P(x,y)=x^4-2x^2 y^2+y^4=(x^2-y^2)^2$. Then $\nabla P(x,y)=(0,0)$ whenever $x=\pm y$.

---

The OP has now said that the condition (say B) that, in addition to condition C, all the coefficients of $P$ be nonnegative was missing.
However, even the conjunction of conditions C and B is not sufficient. Indeed, modify the above example by taking $P(x,y)=\frac14\,(x^4+14x^2 y^2+y^4)$. Then $\nabla P$ is not injective, because $\nabla P(1,1)=\nabla P(u,v)=(8,8)$, where
$$u:=\frac{7}{\left(15-\frac{21}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^{2/3} \sqrt[3]{\sqrt{6
   \left(35901+24010 \sqrt{2}\right)}-108}}-\frac{1}{3}
   \sqrt[3]{\sqrt{6 \left(35901+24010 \sqrt{2}\right)}-108}
=0.322\dots$$
and
$$v:=\sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{3} \left(10+7 \sqrt{2}\right)}
=1.878\dots.$$

---

A Mathematica notebook with the calculations and the illustrating contour plots $\{(x,y)\in[0,2.5]^2\colon P_1(x,y)=8\}$ (blue) and $\{(x,y)\in[0,2.5]^2\colon P_2(x,y)=8\}$ (gold) is shown below, where $(P_1(x,y),P_2(x,y)):=\nabla P(x,y)=(x^3+7 x y^2,7 x^2 y+y^3)$. In particular, the visible three points of intersection of the blue and gold contours are the visible three distinct points at which $\nabla P$ takes the same value $(8,8)$. Looking at the plots, one can easily prove the existence of these three points, thus proving the non-injectivity of $\nabla P$.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I completely forgot to mention that I want all coefficients non-negative, honestly my mistake! Upvoted your answer anyway, but I'm going to change the question if it's okay with you? I'll certainly mention that earlier I typed the question wrong.

Comment: Thank you for your very insightful answer and also for the experiments - I was wrong then, somehow I felt it could be sufficient, but now I need to see if it's necessary! I may post another question in the future then :)